# Batch - Delayed expansion doesn't work with surrounding if clause

Tags: batch-file, scripting, windows-scripting

In the following script I call a subroutine with a string, the maximal length of a substring of that string and a 3rd non-existing variable to get the substring back.

The script should check if the next character after the string with the maximal substrings length is a space and if yes, then cut the string by that space (delete space to) and returning the substring and change the passed string by cutting the substring part. Example:

string: "Hello World Bla"
substringLength: 5

`CALL :get_substring string substringLength substring`

=> string: "World Bla" (no space), substringLength: 5 (no change), substring: "Hello"

This works fine without if clause but it doesn't when i use an if clause, even if i use delayed expansion.

Here is the working code without if statement:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    SET string=Hello World wasserschutzpolizei
    SET /A substringLength=5
    CALL :get_substring string substringLength substring
    ECHO !string!
    ECHO !substring!
    EXIT /B 0
ENDLOCAL

:get_substring
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

    SET "string=!%~1!"
    SET "substringLength=!%2!"
    SET nextChar=!string:~%substringLength%,1!

    REM IF "!nextChar!"==" " (
        SET substring=!string:~0,%substringLength%!
        ECHO !substring!
        SET /A cutSpaceCount=!substringLength!+1
        SET string=!string:~%cutSpaceCount%!

        ECHO !string!

        ENDLOCAL & SET %1=%string% & SET %3=%substring% & EXIT /B 0
    REM ) ELSE (
    REM     Some other case    
    REM )

EXIT /B 0
```

This doesn't work when I comment in the if statement:

```
IF "!nextChar!"==" " (
    SET substring=!string:~0,%substringLength%!
    ECHO !substring!
    SET /A cutSpaceCount=!substringLength!+1
    SET string=!string:~%cutSpaceCount%!

    ECHO !string!

    ENDLOCAL & SET %1=%string% & SET %3=%substring% & EXIT /B 0
) ELSE (
    REM Some other case    
)
```

1. Why does the script doesn't work with an if-statement?
2. How can fix it?

Be aware that my routine should also include an else statement which I cutted out because the problem is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
SET string=!string:~%cutSpaceCount%!
```

When this line is placed inside the `IF` command, then the value of `cutSpaceCount` is changed *inside* the code block (parentheses) of the `IF`, and hence it must be expanded via `!cutSpaceCount!` delayed expansion, *not* via a `%cutSpaceCount%` standard expansion.

You should use something like a "double delayed expansion", that is, similar to this construct:

```
SET string=!string:~!cutSpaceCount!!
```

Of course, this don't work, so the trick is use a `for` command to get the value of the *first* delayed expansion, and then use *the FOR parameter* to complete the second delayed expansion:

```
for /F %%c in ("!cutSpaceCount!") do SET "string=!string:~%%c!"
```

A similar problem happen when the final values in the subroutine are returned to the calling program. This is the final working code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    SET string=Hello World wasserschutzpolizei
    SET /A substringLength=5
    CALL :get_substring string substringLength substring
    ECHO !string!
    ECHO !substring!
    EXIT /B 0
ENDLOCAL

:get_substring
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

    SET "string=!%~1!"
    SET "substringLength=!%2!"
    SET "nextChar=!string:~%substringLength%,1!"

    IF "!nextChar!"==" " (
        SET "substring=!string:~0,%substringLength%!"
        ECHO !substring!
        SET /A cutSpaceCount=!substringLength!+1

        for /F %%c in ("!cutSpaceCount!") do SET "string=!string:~%%c!"

        ECHO !string!
        for /F "delims=" %%s in ("!string!") do for /F "delims=" %%b in ("!substring!") do (
            ENDLOCAL & SET "%1=%%s" & SET "%3=%%b" & EXIT /B 0
        )

    ) ELSE (
        ECHO Some other case    
    )
```

PS - You don't need to expand variable values in `SET /A` command. Instead of:

```
SET /A cutSpaceCount=!substringLength!+1
```

you may simply use:

```
SET /A cutSpaceCount=substringLength+1
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be very confused about the sequence of operations that occurs when delayed expansion has been invoked.

First, the value of `var` is substituted for `%var%`.

Then !var! is evaluated using the results.

The *scope* of this sequence of operations is one *logical* line, which may be one *physical* line or any number of physical lines continued with a terminal `^` or more commonly using a parenthesised sequence of lines.

In your mainline then,

```
CALL :get_substring string substringLength substring
ECHO !string!
ECHO !substring!
ENDLOCAL & SET %1=%string% & SET %3=%substring% & EXIT /B 0
```

Since these statements are *not* within the same *logical* line, they will be *individually* evaluated, so `!var!`==`%var%`.

Within your subroutine (non-IF version),

```
    SET substring=!string:~0,%substringLength%!
    ECHO !substring!
    SET /A cutSpaceCount=!substringLength!+1
    SET string=!string:~%cutSpaceCount%!

    ECHO !string!
```

again are individual statements. The first `set` will first substitute for `substringlength`, and then execute `SET substring=!string:~0,5!` as a second operation.

Each of the `echo`es is a stand-alone statement, and the `!` could (and preferably should) be replaced by `%`.

The `set /a` statement - well, `set /a` allows the *current* value of a variable to be used undecorated, so `SET /A cutSpaceCount=substringLength+1` or `SET /A cutSpaceCount=%substringLength%+1`could be used here with no logical effect.

`ENDLOCAL & SET %1=%string% & SET %3=%substring% & EXIT /B 0` will be evaluated according to the values established by the previous code-sequence.

**However** when you add the `if`, the code is parenthesised and thus becomes one logical statement and acts differently.

The `echo`es then *require* `!` because you want to display the *modified* values within the *code-block*. Since `cutSpaceCount` is not set at the start of the code-block, `SET string=!string:~%cutSpaceCount%!` will be evaluated as `SET string=!string:~!`

and then `ENDLOCAL & SET %1=%string% & SET %3=%substring% & EXIT /B 0` will duly substitute the values of the variables *as they stood when the* `IF`*was encountered*

So, a replacement routine might be

```dos
:get_substring
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "string=!%~1!"
SET "substringLength=!%2!"
SET "substring=!string:~0,%substringLength%!"
SET "string=!string:~%substringLength%!"
IF "%string:~0,1%"==" " SET "string=%string:~1%"
ENDLOCAL & SET "%1=%string%" & SET "%3=%substring%"
EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. I really wasn't aware that everything in paranthesis is interpreted as one logical line. Gives me very different view...

Answer (score 1):

As others already explained, the problem is the line:

```cmd
SET string=!string:~%cutSpaceCount%!
```

because you use immediate expansion (`%`) for variable `cutSpaceCount` which is changed in the same logical line/block of code.

A possible solution is to use `call` like this:

```cmd
    call set "string=%%string:~!cutSpaceCount!%%"
```

`call` introduces another variable expansion phase, so the sequence goes as follows:

1. immediate expansion phase where `%%` becomes `%`:

   ```cmd
   call set "string=%string:~!cutSpaceCount!%"
   ```
2. then delayed expansion occurs (let us assume a sample value of `5`):

   ```cmd
   call set "string=%string:~5%"
   ```
3. another immediate expansion phase introduced by `call` to finally get `%string:~5%`.